# How to get the cheapest fruit

Tags: list

I am practicing DrRacket. Here is the task description:

Recursion is not allowed, you must use filter or map/or/andmap or foldr/foldl to loop through lists. creat a function names cheapest-fruit=bundle and receive a list of fruits as parameter. you input lists of fruit-bundles and want to get the cheapest fruit-bundle. If two fruit-bundles are both the cheapest, then chose the one with more kinds of fruit.

```
(define-struct fruit (name price))
(define (cheapest-fruit-bundle fruits)...)

check-expected:
giving list: (list (list (make-fruit 'apple 3) (make-fruit 'banana 4) (make-fruit 'avocado 5)) 
             (list (make-fruit 'apple 7)(make-fruit 'avocado 5)) 
             (list (make-fruit 'apple 7)(make-fruit 'avocado 9) (make-fruit 'banana 2)))
results: (list (make-fruit 'apple 3) (make-fruit 'banane 4) (make-fruit 'avocado 5))
```

I have solved this problem a bit: I can sum up the price in list and find the smallest element. But I want to get the cheapest bundle and choose the bundle with more kinds of fruits. I get stucked in this step. Furthermore, my function to choose smallest element not meet requirement, because I use recursion of list itself, and I should use map/foldr/foll.filter.

Here is what I have tried；

```
(define (sum-price f)  (foldl + 0 (map fruit-price f)))
(define (smallest l)
    (cond [(empty? (rest l)) (first l)]
        [else (local ((define smallest-in-rest (smallest (rest l))))
                  (if (< (first l) smallest-in-rest) (first l)  smallest-in-rest))]))
(define (cheap-fruit-bundle myfruit) 
  (smallest (map (lambda (fruit-list) (sum-price fruit-list)) myfruit)))
```

my code give out at end only a number.  I have spent hours on this task and can't think up new ideas. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cheapest-budle-and-max-optioin` function process is:

1. If budle-1's price less than budle-2's price we choice budle-1.
2. Or budle-1's price might bigger or equal to budle-2's price. If budle-1's price bigger than budle-2 we choice budle-2.
3. Or two budle price is the same. Than we compare options.

Notice: In here if we have many budles have same price and same option number we still choice one budle.

After finish `cheapest-budle-and-max-optioin` process. Using `foldlr` to compare each budle element in list.

```
(define-struct fruit (name price) #:transparent #:mutable)
                    
(define (filter-cheapest-budle-and-max-optioin budle-list)
  (local [(define (budle-price budle-list)
            (foldl + 0 (map fruit-price budle-list)))
          (define (budle-option-n budle-list)
            (foldl (lambda (x1 x2) (+ x2 1)) 0 budle-list))
          (define (budle-option<? b1 b2)
            (< (budle-option-n b1) (budle-option-n b2)))
          (define (budle-price<? b1 b2) 
            (< (budle-price b1) (budle-price b2)))
          (define (cheapest-budle-and-max-optioin b1 b2)
            (cond
              [(budle-price<? b1 b2) b1]
              [(budle-price<? b2 b1) b2]
              [(budle-option<? b1 b2) b2]
              [else b1]))]
    (foldr cheapest-budle-and-max-optioin (first budle-list) budle-list)))
```

```
;;; TEST

(define budle-list1
  (list
   (list (make-fruit 'apple 0.5)
         (make-fruit 'banana 0.5)) 
   (list (make-fruit 'apple 1)) 
   (list (make-fruit 'avocado 1))))

(define budle-list2
  (list
   (list (make-fruit 'apple 1)
         (make-fruit 'banana 1)) 
   (list (make-fruit 'apple 2)) 
   (list (make-fruit 'avocado 2))))

(filter-cheapest-budle-and-max-optioin budle-list1) ; should be (list (fruit 'apple 0.5) (fruit 'banana 0.5))
(filter-cheapest-budle-and-max-optioin budle-list2) ; should be (list (fruit 'apple 1) (fruit 'banana 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get stuck in a programming problem, a good strategy is to break that problem down into the smallest parts that make sense. You can focus on small problems that are easier to solve, and then combine those parts into the final solution. After you have a working solution, you can refactor if you wish, combining the smaller procedures into larger ones.

Here is one way that you can break your problem down into smaller parts.

You already have a working definition for `sum-price`, although I am going to change the name here:

```
(define-struct fruit (name price))

(define fruit-bundles (list (list (make-fruit 'apple 3)
                                  (make-fruit 'banana 4)
                                  (make-fruit 'avocado 5))
                            (list (make-fruit 'apple 7)
                                  (make-fruit 'avocado 5))
                            (list (make-fruit 'apple 7)
                                  (make-fruit 'avocado 9)
                                  (make-fruit 'banana 2))))

(define (bundle-price bundle)
  (foldl + 0 (map fruit-price bundle)))
```

Now, we want to be able to take a list of `fruit-bundles` and get to the largest, cheapest fruit bundle of the list. The first part of this problem seems to be that we want to get a list of all of the cheapest bundles; after that we can worry about getting the largest bundle.

I'd like to do something like this to get a list of the cheapest bundles, using `filter` with an anonymous procedure that returns true when the bundle price is equal to the minimum bundle price:

```
;; Takes a list of fruit-bundles and returns a list of the cheapest bundles.
(define (cheapest-bundles bundles)
  (filter (lambda (b) (= (bundle-price b)
                         (min-bundle-price bundles)))
          bundles))
```

I already have `bundle-price`, so I just need to write `min-bundle-price`. Since I know that I can `map` over a list of `fruit`s to get a list of prices, I just need to `apply` the `min` procedure to that list:

```
;; Takes a list of fruit-bundles and returns the minimum bundle price.
(define (min-bundle-price bundles)
  (apply min (map bundle-price bundles)))
```

Now I have a way to get a list of the cheapest fruit bundles. Now, lets test the `cheapest-bundles` procedure:

```
scratch.rkt> (cheapest-bundles fruit-bundles)
'((#<fruit> #<fruit> #<fruit>) (#<fruit> #<fruit>))
```

Well, that looks ok, but we can't really see what is in the `fruit` structs. Let's just write a couple of utility procedures to help us see inside the `struct`s:

```
;; A couple of utility functions for inspecting fruits.
(define (inspect-fruit f)
  (list (fruit-name f) (fruit-price f)))

(define (inspect-fruit-bundle bundle)
  (map inspect-fruit bundle))
```

Now let's try again:

```
scratch.rkt> (map inspect-fruit-bundle (cheapest-bundles fruit-bundles))
'(((apple 3) (banana 4) (avocado 5)) ((apple 7) (avocado 5)))
```

That is what we expected; this is a list containing the two cheapest fruit bundles.

Now we need to devise a way to get the largest fruit bundle from this list of the cheapest fruit bundles. But, it could be the case that there are multiple fruit bundles that are the same size; in that case, let's agree to take the first bundle from a list of the largest bundles. So, we plan on creating a list of largest bundles, and we want the first element from that list:

```
;; Takes a list of bundles and returns the largest bundle.
;; If there are multiple largest bundles, the first one in the list is returned.
(define (largest-bundle bundles)
  (car (largest-bundles bundles)))
```

We will need to write `largest-bundles`, which we can write in a way similar to the `cheapest-bundles` procedure by using `filter` to create a list of bundles with counts that are equal to the maximum count for all bundles:

```
;; Takes a list of fruit-bundles and returns a list of the largest bundles.
(define (largest-bundles bundles)
  (filter (lambda (b) (= (bundle-count b)
                         (max-bundle-count bundles)))
          bundles))
```

Before, we needed to get the price for a bundle, but now we will need to get a count of the number of kinds of fruits in a bundle:

```
;; Takes a fruit-bundle and returns the number of fruit elements.
(define (bundle-count bundle)
  (length bundle))
```

Now we just need to write the `max-bundle-count` procedure. We can do this in a way similar to what we did for the `min-bundle-price` procedure, by `apply`ing the `max` procedure to a list of bundle counts:

```
;; Takes a list of fruit-bundles and returns the maximum bundle count.
(define (max-bundle-count bundles)
  (apply max (map bundle-count bundles)))
```

Now we have a procedure that will get us a list of the largest fruit bundles, and another procedure that takes the first one from this list so that multiple hits are handled. Let's test them:

```
scratch.rkt> (map inspect-fruit-bundle (largest-bundles fruit-bundles))
'(((apple 3) (banana 4) (avocado 5)) ((apple 7) (avocado 9) (banana 2)))

scratch.rkt> (inspect-fruit-bundle (largest-bundle fruit-bundles))
'((apple 3) (banana 4) (avocado 5))
```

As expected, `largest-bundles` returns a list of the two largest fruit bundles, and `largest-bundle` returns the first fruit bundle in that list.

Now we just have to combine the above to create the `cheapest-fruit-bundle` procedure:

```
;; Takes a list of fruit-bundles and returns the largest, cheapest bundle.
(define (cheapest-fruit-bundle bundles)
  (largest-bundle (cheapest-bundles bundles)))
```

Remembering to use `inspect-fruit-bundle` so that we can easily read the results, here is the final result:

```
scratch.rkt> (inspect-fruit-bundle (cheapest-fruit-bundle fruit-bundles))
'((apple 3) (banana 4) (avocado 5))
```